# update existing key of HashMap

Tags: java, android, kotlin, concurrency, hashmap

I have HashMap < Integer,String> of length 3:

```
1=>"Value1"
2=>"Value2"
3=>"Value3"
```

Now I want to decrease all keys by 1(if key>1):
Output:

```
1=>"Value2"
2=>"Value3"
```

What I am trying

```
  for (e in hashMap.entries) {
                                val entry = e as Map.Entry<*, *>
                                var keyPos = (entry.key as Int)
                                if (keyPos != -1) {
                                    if (keyPos > 1) {
                                        keyPos = keyPos - 1
                                        if (keyPos != -1) {
                                            hashMap.put(keyPos, entry.value as String?)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

But its not giving required output.

How to make it work without Concurrency exception.

Comment: use two maps, to create a differentiating copy

Comment: Have you tried `Iterator`?

Comment: using iterator inside for can give concurrency  exception

Comment: You can't update a `Map` key, You can only remove the old one and insert its value with a new key.

Comment: Or you can first get the value of 3rd key and then update the value of second key

Comment: HashMap is not ordered so your loop could iterate in order `3=val3, 2=val2, 1=val1` but after first iteration it would modify map to `{2=val3, 1=val1}` (you would place in key 2 previous `val2` with `val3` without assigning that `va2` to key 1). If you are sure that keys are continues series of numbers you can start iterating from minimal number to maximal one explicitly via good old for loop like `for (int i=min; i<max; i++){map.put(i, map.get(i+1));}` after that call `map.remove(max);` to remove previous max value.

Comment: @AskQ is it necessary for you to modify the same instance of the map? or could it just be a new Map Object instead?

Comment: @Hansa no all I'm expecting is the output

Comment: I just gave you the code... Just adapt it to your situation.

Comment: @AskQ updated my answer to be compatible with Java 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: here is the same with Java 7 compatible code (without streams)**

```
HashMap<Integer, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
hashMap.put(1, "test1");
hashMap.put(2, "test2");
hashMap.put(3, "test3");

Map<Integer, String> yourNewHashMap = new HashMap<>();
for (final Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : hashMap.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getKey() != 1) { // make sure index 1 is omitted
        yourNewHashMap.put(entry.getKey() - 1, entry.getValue()); // decrease the index for each key/value pair and add it to the new map
    }
}
```

---

---

**Old answer with streams:**

As a new Map Object is okay for you, I would go with the following stream:
comments are inline

```
HashMap<Integer, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
hashMap.put(1, "test1");
hashMap.put(2, "test2");
hashMap.put(3, "test3");

// use this
Map<Integer, String> yourNewHashMap = hashMap.entrySet().stream()
                                       .filter(es -> es.getKey() != 1) // make sure index 1 is omitted
                                       .map(es -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, String>(es.getKey() - 1, es.getValue())) // decrease the index for each key/value pair
                                       .collect(Collectors.toMap(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey, AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue)); // create a new map
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use [`mapKeys`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-keys.html) extension function, which allows you to redefine the key for a map entry:

```
fun main() {
    val originalMap = mapOf(1 to "value1", 2 to "value2", 3 to "value3")
    val updatedMap = originalMap
        .mapKeys {
            if (it.key > 1) {
                it.key - 1
            } else {
                it.key
            }
        }

    println(updatedMap) // prints: {1=value2, 2=value3}
}
```

Note that this will not update the map in-place, but it will create a new one. Also note that:

> In case if any two entries are mapped to the equal keys, the value of the latter one will overwrite the value associated with the former one.

This means that in case two keys are conflicting, in general you can't know which one will "win" (unless you're using a `LinkedHashMap`, which preserves insertion order).

A more general approach would be to:

1. decrement all keys
2. filter out all non-positive keys

This will require 2 full iterations, though, (unless you use `Sequences`, which are lazily evaluated):

```
fun main() {
    val originalMap = mapOf(1 to "value1", 2 to "value2", 3 to "value3")
    val updatedMap = originalMap
        .mapKeys {
            it.key - 1
        }.filter {
            it.key > 0
        }

    println(updatedMap)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    // Populate the HashMap
    map.put(1, "Value1");
    map.put(2, "Value2");
    map.put(3, "Value3");
    System.out.println("Original HashMap: "
            + map); 
    decreaseAllKeysByOne(map);
}

private static void decreaseAllKeysByOne(HashMap<Integer, String> map) {
    // Add your condition (if key>1)
    HashMap<Integer, String> newMap = new HashMap<>();
    map.remove(1);


    Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
    int i = 1;
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry = iterator.next();
        newMap.put(i, entry.getValue());
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println("Modified HashMap: "
            + newMap);
}
```

Output :

Original HashMap: {1=Value1, 2=Value2, 3=Value3}

Modified HashMap: {1=Value2, 2=Value3}